# Stream wmv Videos from a url in my android app

Tags: android, url, video, streaming, wmv

i am creating an app for my website which contains lots of wmv video files.
and i want to be able to play them in my app.
i understand that android does not support wmv files so my question is:
is there any way for me to do this without to change all videos format in my site?
any modificatios to my videos via code (java - eclipse) or libraries, any loop holes?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to create a site that has streaming video and I could never get Android devices to work with it. Then I found this...

http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android

Comment: Link-only answers can become invalid over time. Could you summarize how this link is helpful to you and relevant to the question at hand?

Comment: Sorry about that, not something I'd normally do! It's not that Android doesn't support WMV files. As I understand it, Android (like everyone else) has dropped Flash support in v4.1. Noteable since this was the channel that Google used to support HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). Problem is that Android doesn't support HLS natively - PROBABLY since it is a proposed draft from Apple! One proposed workaround might be to include a fallback version of the video in an RTSP stream, based upon the client.